# Error compiling the google-http-java-client

Tags: java, maven, google-api-java-client

I am trying to compile the google-http-java-client using Maven.
I tried both versions 1.18.0-rc and 1.19.0-rc-SNAPSHOT, and in both I got the following test error:

```
Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.012 sec <<< FAILURE!
    testEquals(com.google.api.client.util.DateTimeTest)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< FAILURE!
    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Check equals with two different tz specified.
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:34)
    at com.google.api.client.util.DateTimeTest.testEquals(DateTimeTest.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

I am running on Mac with OSX 10.9. Tried to change the `JAVA_HOME` in bash to `1.6` (my default is `1.7`) but same result.

Comment: Turns out that despite this error, the artifact was generated, and I was able to move on (this was just a pre-condition to building the api-client..)

Comment: Yes, the problem is not with compiling, but with tests. It seems there is some timezone problem.